# How to group a dataframe by multiple columns, sum and sort the totals in descending order?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Given the following dataframe:

```
user_id col1 col2
1       A    4
1       A    22
1       A    112
1       B    -0.22222
1       B    9
1       C    0
2       A    -1
2       A    -5
2       K    NA
```

And I want to group by user_id and col1 and count. Then to sort the counts within the groups in descending order.

Here is what I'm trying to do but I don't get the right output:

```
df[["user_id", "col1"]]. \
groupby(["user_id", "col1"]). \
agg(counts=("col1","count")). \
reset_index(). \
sort_values(["user_id", "col1", "counts"], ascending=False)
```

Please advise what should I change to make it work.

Expected output:

```
user_id col1  counts
1       A     3
        B     2
        C     1
2       A     2
        K     1
```

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal done and edited to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GroupBy.size`:

```
In [199]: df.groupby(['user_id', 'col1']).size()
Out[199]: 
user_id  col1
1        A       3
         B       2
         C       1
2        A       2
         K       1
```

**OR:**

```
In [201]: df.groupby(['user_id', 'col1']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
Out[201]: 
   user_id col1  counts
0        1    A       3
1        1    B       2
2        1    C       1
3        2    A       2
4        2    K       1
```

**EDIT:**

```
In [206]: df.groupby(['user_id', 'col1']).agg({'col2': 'size'})
Out[206]: 
              col2
user_id col1      
1       A        3
        B        2
        C        1
2       A        2
        K        1
```

**EDIT-2:** For sorting, use:

```
In [213]: df.groupby(['user_id', 'col1'])['col2'].size().sort_values(ascending=False)
Out[213]: 
user_id  col1
1        A       3
2        A       2
1        B       2
2        K       1
1        C       1
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: But if it was with multiple columns? What should I do? What is the general method. I know about size.

Comment: @SteveS Please check the updated `EDIT` part of my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just to clarify what does the `reset_index(name='counts')` do?

Comment: When you groupby, it puts the grouped columns in index. So `reset_index` creates the index into columns and `name='counts'` gives the name to the column.

Comment: Sure but I don't see the sorting part, how can I ensure the sorting in ascending / descending order?

Comment: Please check `EDIT-2`.

Comment: This is not what I need, I want the output to be as I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: For user 1 (first level) sort the counts, col2 doesn't play any role here

Answer (score 0):

Using the main idea from Mayank answer:

```
df.groupby(["id_user","col1"]).size().reset_index(name="counts").sort_values(["id_user", "col1"], ascending=False)
```

Solved my issue.